# How can I access and reconfigure any widget outside the function it is defined?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I want to access and reconfigure the  **MD_state_ein_Entry** or say any of the below widgets, outside this **Top_MDWindow_func()**

```
def Top_MDWindow_func():
#print(MD_checkbox.get())
if MD_checkbox.get()==1:
    MD_top_window= tk.Toplevel()
    MD_top_window.geometry('500x350')
    MD_top_window.resizable(0, 0)
    MD_top_window.title("Multi Division Client")
    MD_top_window.config(bg="white")
    
    Heading_Frame=Frame(MD_top_window,bg="white", borderwidth=1, relief="groove" ,padx=120,pady=8)
    Heading_Frame.pack()
    MD_title_lbl=Label(Heading_Frame,bg="white",text="MULTI DIVISION CLIENT",font=("Helvetica", 16,"bold")).pack()
    
    
    Body_Frame=Frame(MD_top_window,bg="white", borderwidth=0.5, relief="sunken",height=285, width=483)
    Body_Frame.pack()
    Body_Frame.pack_propagate(0)
    
    MD_state_ein_label=Label(Body_Frame,bg="white", text='State EIN ',font=("Helvetica", 10) ).place(relx=0.02, rely=0.10)          
    MD_state_ein_Entry = Entry(Body_Frame)
    MD_state_ein_Entry.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.10, width=150, height=22)
    
    MD_client_name_label=Label(Body_Frame,bg="white", text='Client Name ',font=("Helvetica", 10) ).place(relx=0.02, rely=0.25)          
    MD_client_name_Entry = Entry(Body_Frame)
    MD_client_name_Entry.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.25, width=150, height=22)
    
    MD_fein_label=Label(Body_Frame,bg="white", text='FEIN ',font=("Helvetica", 10) ).place(relx=0.02, rely=0.40)          
    MD_fein_Entry = Entry(Body_Frame)
    MD_fein_Entry.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.40, width=150, height=22)
```

when I am trying to access these widgets from other function i am getting this error *NameError: name 'MD_state_ein_Entry' is not defined*, I understood why I am getting this error and now I am looking for  solution.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `global MD_state_ein_Entry` ?

Comment: Yeah I got it Thanks